# count the number of values in data frame's column that exist in another data frame's column

Tags: python, pandas, date, count

I have two data frames:

df1:

| Index | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-03-21 20:10:00 |
| 1 | 2016-03-22 21:09:00 |
| 2 | 2016-05-03 17:05:00 |

df2:

| Index | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2016-03-21 20:10:00 |
| 1 | 2016-03-21 21:00:00 |
| 2 | 2016-03-22 21:09:00 |
| 3 | 2016-05-03 17:05:00 |
| 4 | 2017-06-01 16:10:00 |

There's probably a really simple way to do this but how would I count the number of values in the df1 Date column that are also in the df2 Date column? (These are not unique value counts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest approach to solve your problem will be use `set` intersection(find common element from set).
Eg:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({"date":['2016-03-21 20:10:00','2016-03-22 21:09:00','2016-05-03 17:05:00']})

df2=pd.DataFrame({"date":['2016-03-21 20:10:00','2016-03-21 21:00:00',
                '2016-03-22 21:09:00','2016-05-03 17:05:00','2017-06-01 16:10:00']})

print(len(set(df1.date) & set(df2.date))) # 3
```

This will just convert that specified column to `python-set` and find common between them.

---

If you want to use Pandas then you can use [pandas.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to get the common rows based on the columns.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2)
print(len(df3)) # 3
```

and count common rows using `len` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [**isin** function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html):

```
len(df1[df1.Date.isin(df2.Date)])
```

**Output:**

```
3
```